# Error in running c# windows application

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I wrote a c# windows application and I want to run it on other computer without any installation.

I setup the netCFSetup v35 but when I run my application this error was apeare :

the application failed to init....

can anyone help me please?...

Comment: Why are you installing the Compact Framework?

Comment: Just create a console app or windows app in VS.NET that generates a .exe file that can be executed on other machines without any installation. The only thing the other machine would need to have is a .NET Framework installed.

Comment: because of its size(about 50MB)

Comment: If you're targeting the full .NET 3.5 Framework and using features from it, using the Compact Framework is not even an option. You must use the full framework, or don't use features from the full framework and target the Compact Edition, in which there will be some compromises in the features you can use.

Comment: I have a feeling that @DavidAnderson is correct. Is there any reason as to why you've used version 3.5 as opposed to 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are installing wrong framework for you application.

Since its a windows application i suggest your install .Net Framework of Desktop. The one you are installing is of Compact Framework (CF in filename netCFSetup v35) which was used for Windows Mobile 6.5 or earlier.

If you created your app in .Net 3.5 version. install this version

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21

**To know in which version of .Net Framework your app is written in, go to properties section of project. There you will get your version number.**

Comment: but .net framework is too Heavy,i need smallest version but .net framework is about 230MB

Comment: In your development system (where Visual Studio is installed), search for file name dotNetFx35setup.exe. Its a 2.73 MB file. Its your offline system. This is the same file i asked you to download from the link provided in my answer.

Comment: please...

anybody can help!!??

i need a small size of .net framework v35...

is there any version?

Comment: when i install that ,it needs to download about 54MB to complete installation,is there any offline setup?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: i use 2010 and my application was developed in .net... v3.5

Comment: Then upgrade target framework of your app from 3.5 to 4.0. Full 4.0 offline installer comes with VS 2010. Search file name dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64 in dev machine (File Size around 49 MB).

Comment: tnx but it needs WIC to be install before installation of .net

Comment: WCI or WIC (Windows Imaging Component)?

Comment: You can download it from here. Choose your language. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=32